# How to wrap an existing slf4j logger into a kotlin logger?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-logging

Given an existing slf4j logger, I would like to wrap it into an kotlin-logging logger.

The classes / methods to do that already exists in the library but are internal, so I can't call them:
`mu.internal.KLoggerFactory.wrapJLogger()`

Is there another way to do it, which is accessible to users of the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use the extension method: `Logger.toKLogger()` since 1.7.6. see this issue for more details: https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/issues/88